# Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Int'

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm trying to check if a number is less than 0, and is getting an error

```
Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Int'
```

It works in Xcode 8, but after I migrated to Xcode 9, it doesn't work anymore. I have another project that uses the exact same code and is working in Xcode 9, I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Here's the code

```
let percent = Double(data.percent)
if(percent==0){
  cell.lblPercent.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
} else if(percent<0){ // Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Int'
  cell.lblPercent.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.92, green: 0.0, blue: 0.047, alpha: 1.0)
} else {
  cell.lblPercent.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.11, green: 0.66, blue: 0.019, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Comment: You can convert Int to Double or Double to Int and then check condition. But, as per your code I suggest you convert to 0 value in double and then check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that `percent` constant is an optional. Swift 3 has removed comparisons between an optional and a non-optional with the same base type. Conversion between Int literal (0) and Double type is implicit (so this is not a problem here).

You can either unwrap the optional:

```
if let percent = percent, percent < 0 {
}
```

or use `??` operator like this:

```
if ((percent ?? 0) < 0) {
}
```

You could also use nil coalescing operator in the definition of the `percent` constant (*if that is appropriate for your use case*¹):

```
let percent = Double(data.percent) ?? 0
```

¹ *Note that by doing so you will change the flow of the program when percent is `nil` (the first branch for `percent==0` condition will be executed instead of the last `else` branch).*

Answer (score 0):

If the string cannot be parsed to a `Double`, the `Double.init` will return `nil`. Comparing `nil` with another number does not make sense. You have to solve that optional somehow, e.g.:

```
let percent = Double(data.percent) ?? 0
```

This has actually changed already in Swift 3 (see [SE-0121](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md)). I am assuming you were still working in Swift 2 even in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 0):

If take a closer look at the error:

**Binary operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double?' and 'Int'**

You are trying to compare an optional value(`Double?`) to a non optional value(`Int`) and because of this the debugger is not able to a comparision.

You can resolve it by unwrappping the optional value using `guard` / `if let` constructs or provide a default value using the nil-coalescing operator `??`

with guard or if let:

```
if let percent = Double(data.percent) {
  textColor = .black
}
```

or provide a default value if it can be unwrapped

```
let percent: Double = Double(data.percent) ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

"percent" was created by converting a string to Double. That conversion can obviously fail, for example if your string contained "abc". So in newer Swift versions, that comparison between Double? and an Int is not allowed anymore.

Before you create code that compiles, you need to decide what outcome you want. The simplest way to implement your code is

```
if let percent = Double(data.percent) {
    // Your code goes here
} else {
    // Code for the case that data.percent cannot be converted
}
```

If you decided that non-convertible data should be treated like a zero for example then you could write

```
let percent = Double(data.percent) ?? 0.0
```

That way, anything that cannot be converted will be turned into a zero. Obviously you must only do that if it is the right thing to do.

If you are absolutely one hundred percent sure that the data can be converted then you write

```
let percent = Double(data.percent)!
```

Now "percent" will not be optional anymore. If data.percent cannot be converted, your app will crash. As I said, if you are absolutely one hundred percent sure it can be converted.